# Soundcloud Persisting Connection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, persistence, soundcloud

I just can't understand the SDK documentation, there is too much missing.

I have started a connection, which is fine, and can retrieve my user details. However, if I refresh the page, I lose my connection. I guess this is because I am not persisting the connection in any way. I cannot find any documentation about how to do this. Do I store something in a cookie, or what?

Here is my connection code:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "XXXX",
    redirect_uri: "YYY",
});

// initiate auth popup
function connectSC(){
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
      //get my favourites
          getFavourites();
  });
});
}
```

Any ideas how I can make sure that my connection is persisted so that if I refersh the page, I can still make calls to SC.get, without having to do an SC.connect first?

Any help would be much appreciated

Regards
James

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check `SC.isConnected()` at the start. This is persisted between pages and should do the trick. https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/blob/master/src/sc/connect.coffee#L52

```
if (SC.isConnected()) {
  doCoolStuffWithTheAPI();
} else {
  SC.connect(function () {
    doCoolStuffWithTheAPI();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about that soundcloud api, but i doubt it is possible to do what you want.

an http-request is self-contained, so refreshing your page will result in a new request with new renderings, and you probably need a new connection.

thats one of the main reasons why ajax is so popular, you dont need a page refresh.